# NSWindow unintentionally hides when application resigns active

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Whenever my `NSApplication` resigns active (e.g, switch to another App), the main `NSWindow` for the application becomes hidden (if I go into mission control the app's window doesn't appear there).

The `NSApplication` methods `-applicationWillResignActive` and `-applicationDidResignActive` have not been implemented

I've also tried setting `-canHide` to `NO` on the `NSWindow`

Does anybody have any ideas how I could troubleshoot this, or better yet, what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the `hidesOnDeactive` property of the window in IB?

> Indicates whether the window is removed from the screen when its application becomes inactive.

This is the default value for panels:

> The default for `NSWindow` is `NO`; the default for `NSPanel` is `YES`.

Comment: That sounded really promising, but it looks to be unchecked :\

Comment: Just to be sure I programmatically set the -hideOnDeactivate property for the window to NO, it's still hiding

Comment: Hmmm, that is really weird. Is it an instance of `NSWindow` or `NSPanel`? Did you try to simply add another window?

Comment: It inherits from an NSWindow, so initially I thought that... but now I'm not sure.  It seems to be acting like an NSPanel?  I'm not sure though, I haven't really ever worked with an NSPanel.  Maybe this is useful information: The NSApplication first receives the applicationWillResignActive notification.  At this point, the "NSWindow" in question is already hidden.  Then the NSWindow only sends the resignKey and resignMain notifications.  The NSApplication then receives the applicationDidResignActive notification.  At this point I can actually force my window to show up in this method

Comment: If I set the NSWindow's canHide property to NO, and then after forcing my window to show, try to hide it, it will not work.  However, if I click on Hide in the dock for my application, it will Hide.  If I switch my canHide property to YES, and (again, after the applicationDidResignActive -> force window to show) the window will then Hide.  I am pretty stumped at this point

Comment: Found it.  Coworker had inserted a child NSPanel that was mucking up things.  Found it through your suggestion, thanks!